# Regarding assembly language programming in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, gpio, assembly

I am learning assembly language programming in Raspberry Pi 2 model B. I know about Code::Blocks and `gdb`. Using assembly language the processor's register can be controlled, but I want to control the peripheral's registers (BCM2835 peripheral) because I need to control interrupts.

Can any one suggest, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I expect your terminology is incorrect.

If you want to control interrupts you will either have to go bare metal or write a Linux kernel driver.

If you use Raspbian from userland you can not "control" interrupts.  However you can request a callback when an interrupt happens.

Do you want to use interrupts to control peripherals?  To do what?

Comment: By userland , event can be detected in a GPIO but that is very slow for my application thats why I am trying to do it with real interrupt . When I looked at BCM 2835 data sheet in page 109, it give information about interrupts and in page no. 112 itmentions about Registers. So I think that to controlinterrupt , these register field should be set.t

Comment: It might be worth adding that information to your question.  It may be useful.  What sort of interrupt rates are you talking about?  How often and how frequent?

Comment: requirement is about 100 Khz or more.

Comment: @vivek Okay.  You won't be able to use interrupts for that from userland.  There is a latency of about 50 µs between interrupt and userland process notification.  You will lose interrupts.  I suggest you have a look at my [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library which will capture the events down to the microsecond level.  However unless you have very little processing to do do I can't see those data rates being handled for more than a few seconds or so.